# Simulate pressing tab key with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keydown, simulate

I have some textboxes on a .net-page and want to achieve the following with jQuery: if the user presses return, the program should behave "as if" he had used the tab key, thus, selecting the next element. I tried the following code (and some more):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tb').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $(this).trigger("keydown", [9]);
            alert("return pressed");
        } 
    });
});
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="tb"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="tb"></asp:TextBox>
```

but it just does not work! Missing something, making a mistake?

Here some links I used

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807083/how-to-send-a-keypress-trigger-using-jquery)

Comment: Well, no; because you're not passing the event to the function. You need to use: `$('.tb').keypress(function(e){` then the function has access to the event, and thence `event.keyCode`, although I think `e.which` is the normalized jQuery version (which may, or may not, be necessary).

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? What happens? Get any JS-errors?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson: nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating the TAB keydown: focusing next element as determined by \`tabIndex\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303507/simulating-the-tab-keydown-focusing-next-element-as-determined-by-tabindex)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsbin.com/ofexat

```
$('.tg').bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 13) {
    $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

or the loop version: http://jsbin.com/ofexat/2

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if a following sibling element is found, or am I mistaken? But it should work in any case.

Comment: Do You want to loop the elements?

Comment: If the elements are like this will not working. `<input class="input"><br><input class="input"><button>` Enter on first input can't find next input but found `br`. Use `next('.input')` still not working.

Answer (score 13):

From multiple answers I have combined the perfect solution for me where enter acts as tab on inputs and select and takes focus on next input, select or textarea while allows enter inside text area.

```
 $("input,select").bind("keydown", function (e) {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if(keyCode === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('input, select, textarea')
         [$('input,select,textarea').index(this)+1].focus();
     }
 });
```

Comment: This is almost perfect for my project, but I needed it not to tab to every single radio button. A loop to skip inputs with the same name did the trick. `var nextInput = $('input,select,textarea')[$('input,select,textarea').index(this)+1];
            while ($(this).attr('name') === $(nextInput).attr('name')) {
                nextInput = $('input,select,textarea')[$('input,select,textarea').index(nextInput)+1];
            }
`

It still gets stuck inside hidden inputs. Usually they could be at the top of the form, but I have a conditionally hidden input that has to reappear in the right place.

Comment: `if (keyCode === 13) {` is better

Answer (score 12):

I created a [simple jQuery plugin](https://github.com/marklagendijk/jQuery.tabbable) which does solve this problem. It uses the ':tabbable' selector of jQuery UI to find the next 'tabbable' element and selects it.

Example usage:

```
// Simulate tab key when enter is pressed           
$('.tb').bind('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        if(event.shiftKey){
            $.tabPrev();
        }
        else{
            $.tabNext();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't used the hole plugin but the selector with :tabbable was a nice brain shot :P

Comment: please note that `:tabbable` requres jQuery UI dependency

Comment: I like it!  For my use case, I modified the javascript to include `selectables.eq(prevIndex).select();` at the end of each function to also simulate the way the tab key selects the contents of the next input.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(this).trigger({
    type: 'keypress',
    which: 9
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn´t react.

Comment: Check the JS Console for errors, also try running the code separately in a clean HTML file and see if you can produce the specific situation needed. Than try to move it to your master file.

Comment: Can you provide a good fiddle for that? Because I tried it, and it didn't work. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/gtbUp/).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either - [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYNLjE?editors=101).

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I have updated the fiddle.

`$(function() {
    $('#first').focus();
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#first').trigger({
            type: 'keypress',
            which: 9
        });
    });
    
    $('#first').on('keypress', function(e) {
     if (e.which == 9) {
       alert("Tab Pressed!");
        $(this).next().focus();
      }
    });
});`